# Error while selecting a field in Process Builder

Tags: workflow, process-builder, standard-objects, process

I am using process builder for my opportunity record. I wish to add a criteria in process builder to define the criteria for the action group. In set conditions sections I select a field from the opportunity object and click choose. I get an error as show in the attached screen shot. I am unable to add any of the fields to the set condition section.

Please provide your insights.[image]

Answer (score 0):

This happens often.  Process Builder is nice and buggy. Keep trying and it should work.  Sometimes you have to close out of the page.  I usually see it going away after 3 or so attempts.  If you continue having issues check the FLS of the field just for safe measures, though it shouldn't have an affect (had it error a Flow from being saved once).

Comment: Ok I will try this and comment back